# MYSQL Explain Giving an "Impossible WHERE" with SELECT Count(x) Query

Tags: mysql, database, select, where-clause

It seems I'm getting an "impossible WHERE" on a SELECT query. I've posted two queries below, which differentiate in the subquery. What these queries do is check to see if a user has saved something once before, before updating a count. I am using SELECT for testing purposes, but the actual query would be using UPDATE:

```
UPDATE articles SET article_count = article_count+1 
WHERE id = 2343243 AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM posts as p
    WHERE p.post_id = 2343243 AND p.user_id = 3
) = 1;
```

The following two queries are what I'm using to test to see if the data is in the table (for testing only):

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT a.id 
FROM articles as a 
WHERE a.id = 2343243 AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM posts as p
    WHERE p.post_id = a.id AND p.user_id = 3
) = 1;
```

*Query 1* returns `Impossible WHERE` in EXPLAIN.
The select_type of the query #2 is SUBQUERY.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT a.id 
FROM articles as a 
WHERE a.id = 2343243 AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM posts as p
    WHERE p.post_id = 2343243 AND p.user_id = 3
) = 1;
```

*Query 2* returns `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables` in EXPLAIN.
The select_type of the *Query 2* is DEPENDENT SUBQUERY.

**Question:** Any ideas on how to make this not an impossible WHERE query? And also, which would be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading on Mysql.com about Impossible WHERE, it isn't really a good idea to work with such a constraint as WHERE 1 = 1 in a query:

> Because it is never possible for this condition to be true, the
>   EXPLAIN statement will show the words Impossible WHERE. Informally, we
>   at MySQL say that the WHERE has been optimized away.

Mysql.com: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-eliminating-dead-code.html

I've decided to ditch that query for a new query I've written that utilizes indexes for both the main query and the subquery which is a faster solution and seemingly less complex:

```
UPDATE articles 
SET article_count = IF (
    (SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE post_id = 2343243 AND user_id = 3) = 1, article_count+1, article_count) 
WHERE id = 2343243;
```

Answer (score 0):

a prepared statement that doesn't use an actual constant might help (if mysql is using the actual constant that you are testing to declare impossibility based on the data)

Comment: So it appears that all WHERE 1 = 1, WHERE 0 > 1, WHERE 0 < 1, etc are all Impossible WHERE's. I tried using HAVING but I get an Impossible HAVING. Care to elaborate more on how to properly use a prepared statement for this query?

Comment: sorry i am out of my depth and i can't get hold of a mysql installation =(